# Send emails with HTML/CSS in line with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, html-email

I'm trying to make a "simple" thing, need to send a stylized email, do not want to send only text, need to insert HTML tags and CSS. Before working with CakePHP I wore PHPMailer, where I could send emails with HTML and CSS in line.

I'm working on a project that uses the CakePHP framework.
In the documentation, it seems to me that he has the possibility to send emails with embedded CSS in the same way I did, but all emails sent go with the HTML tags displayed as if they were simple texts.

```
$ Email = new CakeEmail ('smtp');
$ Email-> template ('contact');
$ Email-> emailFormat ('html');
$ Email-> to ('****************');
$ Email-> subject ('Contact - Contact Us');
$ Email-> viewVars (array ('contact' => $ this-> request-> data));
$ Email-> send ();
```

This is the code I'm using to send emails and view is:

```
<Html>
<Body>
    <P> <strong> Contact Received </ strong> </ p>

    ? <P> Date: <strong> <? Php echo date ("d / m / Y"); ?> </ Strong> </ p>
    <P> Name: <strong> </ strong> </ p> <? Php echo $ contact ['Contact'] ['name']?>
    <P> Telephone: <strong> <? Php echo $ contact ['Contact'] ['phone']?> </ Strong> </ p>
    <P> Email: <strong> <? Php echo $ contact ['Contact'] ['email']> </ strong> </ p>
    <P> Subject: <strong> <? Php echo $ contact ['Contact'] ['subject']?> </ Strong> </ p>
    <P> Message: <strong> <? Php echo $ contact ['Contact'] ['message']?> </ Strong> </ p>
</ Body>
```

But when I leave the parameter `$email-> emailFormat ('html');` messages sent arrive blank, when I remove this parameter leaving the default (text) message to arrive with the HMTL on the screen as if it was plain text and if I put it to "both" does quite nothing.

This Layout:

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

Comment: There are a couple approaches here. Use an CSS-inline package to do it for you (they're out there). This would probably be appropriate in a view class, then emails using that class would automatically css-inline rendered content. The other approach is to use a helper that just has special methods for items (buttons, etc.) that return html with inline'd css. EDIT: I read the title first before I noticed that it's printing html. I'll leave the comment as I feel it's useful. As for printing HTML, is your email client configured to receive HTML?

Comment: @jeremyharris
Hello, I do not know if I understand very well what you mean.
But the emails are getting these test email is gmail, when I used the phpmailer in another company I could send html without him to write as plain text ...
I am now working with the cake and wanted to do it natively, send a formatted email with inline css and he could interpret this, I believe the problem is with mimeType or headers

Comment: Sending as html using `emailFormat` is sufficient, no extra headers need to be sent. Try with basic HTML, i.e., `<p>test</p>`, then add from there. Also make sure your view doesn't have `<html>`/`<body>` as your HTML email **layout** probably has those tags already.

Comment: @jeremyharris You've helped me a bit if I send `$email->send('<p> Hello </ p>')` and commenting on the template line email arrives right, ie does not show the tag p. But when I add the template, not show the content

Comment: It would probably be best to edit your question and include more information, such as the template view and the template layout. I can't debug with you via comments.

Comment: @jeremyharris
Thank you, thank you managed to find the error.
I'll post

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what went wrong, but after both managed to solve:

First, I removed the head boy html tags of email layouts
Second, I noticed that my template's html folder was empty, while the template txt folder was valued, after adding the value in the html folder everything worked file.